# Restructure data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have survey data structured as follows:

```r
df <- data.frame(userid = c(1, 2, 3), 
                 pos1 = c("itemA_1", "itemB_1", "itemA_2"),
                 pos2 = c("itemB_1", "itemC_2", "itemC_1"),
                 pos3 = c("itemC_5", "itemA_4", "itemB_3")
                 )
df

> df
  userid    pos1    pos2    pos3
1      1 itemA_1 itemB_3 itemC_3
2      2 itemB_1 itemC_1 itemA_1
3      3 itemA_2 itemC_4 itemB_1
```

In the survey several items (itemA, itemB, itemC ...) were rated on a five-point likert-skale ranging from 1 to 5. The order in which the items were answered was also saved.

For example in the above data.frame `user 1` rated itemA first and the rating was 1. Then he rated itemB and the rating was 3. Finally he rated itemC and the rating was 3.
`user 2` started with itemB and the rating was 1 etc.

Obviously, that structure is not very useful to analyse the data. So I'd rather have it in a form like this:

```r
userid  itemA  itemB  itemC ...
     1      1      3      3
     2      1      1      1
     3      2      1      4
```

But how can I get there? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Get the data in long format, `separate` the rating value from `'item'` and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('pos'), names_to = NULL) %>%
  separate(value, c('item', 'rating'), sep = '_', convert = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = rating)

#  userid itemA itemB itemC
#   <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#1      1     1     1     5
#2      2     4     1     2
#3      3     2     3     1
```